# Dual Boot issues windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

OS windows 11 on hp w/ 1 TB memory. This is a new laptop that I just bought and have nothing on yet.

I am trying to dual boot windows with ubuntu 20.04

following these steps [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-Hv9hOaKso&list=WL&index=2) except that I used Rufus to create a bootable USB drive because for some reason Balena was not working for me.

The problem as you can see pic that I do not see the unallocated free space? And I also do not see the install ubuntu alongside Windows boot! So from the second image what should I select?

```
/dev/nvmeOn1

or 

/dev/nvme1n1
```

https://ibb.co/2M1J5jY

https://ibb.co/m8dcy2b

Update laptop specification:

```
HP ENVY 17 Laptop PC
•1 TB Intel® SSD + 32 GB Intel® Optane™ memory
•32 GB DDR4-3200 SDRAM (2 x 16 GB)
•Windows 11 Home 64 ADV
•Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 (up to 4.7 GHz, 12 MB L3 cache, 4 cores) + Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics
```

Comment: It's probably because your disk subsystem is set to RAID or RST. Check your BIOS. Search here on AU for "RST" and you'll find the solution.

Comment: What brand/model system? Some require additional UEFI settings. Many (even new) require UEFI firmware & SSD firmware updates. And if very new hardware, you may need 21.10 to have newest kernel & drivers.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: What are these "require UEFI firmware & SSD firmware updates"?

Comment: For example, one new machine would not even boot without using acpi=0, but then only one CPU core was visible.  That problem went away after the motherboard firmware update. Check with your vendor for any updates.  At power on, you usually get a screen with all sorts of BIOS/frimware information for the version installed.

Comment: @heynnema I can not find what you suggested. Are you referring to UEFI HII Configuration? I searched the bois could not find raid to rest but found this here https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/How-to-re-enable-Intel-RST-in-the-BIOS-setup/td-p/7778036 and the UEFI was disable. I unable it and tried again but the same.

Comment: @Rick The disk subsystem settings have nothing to do with UEFI. Did you search here on AU for "RST" as I suggested?

Comment: The linked I shared is what I got when searching the terms you suggested!