# How to make filesystem on unallocated space in windows for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to solve this problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384808/dual-boot-issues-windows-11?noredirect=1#comment2389481_1384808) following steps [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) and someone suggested the following to me

> The installer may have expected you to make a partition on the free space, before you went into the install step. Most installers force you thru this step. You have to 1. make a partition, 2. put a filesystem on it, usually ext3 or ext4, and 3. give it a mount point name (eg /).
> You usually need to make a minimum of a root filesystem partition ( called /), and a swap partition. So when you did step 4, you only made free space, not a partition.

[unallocated memory see here](https://ibb.co/pPWrKKV)

Would someone shows me how to make this unallocated memory partition of the filesystem?

Comment: Which file system... Windows or Ubuntu? In your other question, did you search here for "RST" as I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

To make a partition and file system yourself, you use disk partitioning software, either in Windows or in an Ubuntu live session. However, if you are going to install Ubuntu **the installer will take care of that**.

A very good tutorial for Ubuntu 20.04 with screenshots is available over at [Itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/). Of course, the ultimate reference remains the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/index.html).

If you select the option "**Install Ubuntu alongside Windows**", the installer will allow you to shrink the Windows partition to make space for a linux partition. However, if you do not see that option, then you must create and assign partitions manually from within the installer by selecting "**Something else**".

- The easiest is the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows". If you already have the free space, there will be no need to further resize the Windows partition. You just hit <kbd>Install Now</kbd> on the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" screen, and the system will automatically create and format a single root partition to install the system. Swap is implemented as a swap file, not a separate partition nowadays.
- Else, if you do not see that option, you need to select "Something Else". You then need to create a partition yourself in the free space. While the tutorial shows how to set up a separate `swap` space and separate partition for `/home`, you can, for simplicity, also just stick to a single partition. Once you assigned the partition, a click on the <kbd>Install Now</kbd> button will automatically create and format the partition.

Comment: @vandium "is available over at Itsfoss. " I listed this I'm my post I am familiar with this link. But my problem is that I do not have this option  "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows",

Comment: Please read the link *and* my answer again, in particular bullet point two.